# Revoke third party account links programatically

Tags: apex, account

Is it possible to revoke third-party account links in apex?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes , we can do it programaticlly , like :

// revoke the third party accont links

```
            Auth.AuthToken.revokeAccess(SsoProvider.id, Provider, userId, thirdPartyAccountLink.RemoteIdentifier);
```

We can query the third party account link using SOQL by - "ThirdPartyAccountLink" sObject