# Unable to deleteThirdPartyAccountLink record in RegistrationHandler apex class for SSO

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, registration-handler

I'm stuck in deleting ThirdPartyAccountLink record in RegistrationHandler apex class for SSO. After contacting salesforce support I got delete access on ThirdPartyAccountLink  object.

My class is working as expected when user login first time but when I change the user id for that user and try to login it gave me below error:
**"Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0Jr0v00000000FQCAY; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 788178633-264969 (188355293): []"**

After changing Id of User A from xxx to yyy, then User A should land on profile of user having YYY id. Currently even after changing Id User A still landing on profile of xxx id.

Please let me know if any confusion is there.

Code :

```java
    global class RegistrationHandlerSSO implements Auth.RegistrationHandler {
    
        global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) {
    
            //Querying all users
            List<User> userList = new List<User>([
                SELECT  Id
                FROM    User
                WHERE   Id =: data.attributeMap.get('alt_username') AND
                        IsActive = true and
                        SFDC_License_Type__c = 'Customer Community Plus Login'
            ]);
    
            User uId;
            boolean generateUser = true;
    
            for (User u:userList) {
    
                //Checking that current user is already there in system or not.
                //If yes, performing below operations
                if (u.Id == data.attributeMap.get('alt_username')) {
    
                    Id userIds= u.Id;
    
                    //Fetch ThirdPartyAccountLink records associated with this user and delete it using
                    // Auth.AuthToken.revokeAccess() method
                    List<ThirdPartyAccountLink> thirdPartyActLink = new List<ThirdPartyAccountLink>(
                        [SELECT Handle, Provider, SsoProviderName, UserId, ThirdPartyAccountLinkKey,
                                user.contact.Account.Id, remoteIdentifier, SsoProvider.id
                         FROM   ThirdPartyAccountLink
                         WHERE  UserId =: userIds
                         LIMIT  1]);
    
                    if(!thirdPartyActLink.isEmpty())
                    Auth.AuthToken.revokeAccess(
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].SsoProvider.id,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].Provider,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].UserId,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].remoteIdentifier
                            );
    
                    //Marking this boolean as false to avoid creating new user
                    generateUser = false;
    
                    //if user is aleadythere in system paas it to updateUser() method to avoid linking
                    // Id change
                    updateUser(u.Id, portalId, data);
                    uId = u;
                }
            }
    
            return(uId);
        }
    
        global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) {
    
            // checking for ID whether it same as logged in community user. if not then update it
            if(userId != data.attributeMap.get('alt_username')) {
                userId = data.attributeMap.get('alt_username');
            }
    
            List<User> userList = new List<User>([
                SELECT  Id
                FROM    User
                WHERE   Id =: userId
            ]);
    
            for (User u:userList) {
    
                List<ThirdPartyAccountLink> thirdPartyActLink = new List<ThirdPartyAccountLink>(
                        [SELECT Handle, Provider, SsoProviderName, UserId, ThirdPartyAccountLinkKey,
                                user.contact.Account.Id, remoteIdentifier, SsoProvider.id
                         FROM   ThirdPartyAccountLink
                         WHERE  UserId =: u.Id
                         LIMIT  1]);
    
                    if(!thirdPartyActLink.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            Auth.AuthToken.revokeAccess(
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].SsoProvider.id,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].Provider,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].UserId,
                                thirdPartyActLink[0].remoteIdentifier
                            );
                        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
                            System.debug('@@@Error while deleteImmediate::'+e);
                            System.Debug('Cause: ' + e.getCause());
                            System.Debug('TypeName: ' + e.getTypeName());
                            System.Debug('getDmlFieldNames: ' + e.getDmlFieldNames(0));
                            System.Debug('getDmlFields: ' + e.getDmlFields(0));
                            System.Debug('getDmlId: ' + e.getDmlId(0));
                            System.Debug('getDmlMessage: ' + e.getDmlMessage(0));
                            System.Debug('getDmlType: ' + e.getDmlType(0));
                            System.Debug('getNumDml: ' + e.getNumDml());
                            System.Debug('Message: ' + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
    
                    User u2 = new User(id=u.Id);
                    update(u2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me on this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try [revoking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196978/revoke-third-party-account-links-programatically/) instead of deleting

Comment: I did that as well, but it gave me error as "We can’t log you in because of an authentication error."
I want user to be able to login with new ID instead of giving authentication error, can it be possible?

Comment: Return the right User from `createUser(...)`. If the User record already exists and you want to use that record instead of creating a new one, locate that record and return it.

Comment: Revoking method works for scenario when User Id is changed. I'll check for newly created user, whether it is able to login or not after these change in code

Comment: Thanks @identigral , by making few code changes it worked as expected. I've update my code in question, which is working now.

Answer (score 1):

@Snehal not completely sure whether this is still relevant. But the solution could be in providing the Provider name to revokeAccess() in lowercase.

Some other useful things to know:

- deleteImmediate() currently (March '21) faces a known bug regarding TPAL destruction, so SF supports shared to only use revokeAccess();
- revokeAccess() requires the Provider name to be lowercase (even while not documented)
- insertImmediate() on TPALs requires the TPAL Unique key to not exist in the system yet. In other words, when reparenting, make sure the original record is deleted/revoked access before trying to insert the same TPAL to another User

In case you like to read more on this, please find this post where I list several challenges I faced when implementing:
https://www.foxy-solutions.com/salesforce/reparent-thirdpartyaccountlinks/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147236)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava and identigral thanks for your replies. I thought the answer already provided the direct response sufficiently, but please find the answer to be updated and contain a summary of findings shared in the blog post.